# MySql - How can I improve this query?

Tags: mysql, query, performance, query-performance

I have the following table: http://pastebin.com/XH6FvhZ8

and the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM `job_logs`
      ORDER BY id DESC) AS job_logs_tmp
WHERE (job_logs_tmp.user_id = ? AND job_logs_tmp.workflow_state = ?)
GROUP BY chain, subchain, job_type
```

here is the explain of this query: http://pastebin.com/AjXgzRBA

this query usually takes over 4K ms to execute, any ideas how I can speed the query execution? I have no problem adding indexes to table if needed

thanks!

Comment: You want a [`greatest-n-per-group`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+mysql?sort=votes&pagesize=50) query. Search the SO site for this tag and you'll find plenty of similar queries and answers.

Comment: remove the `ORDER BY id DESC`... the `group by` will destroy the ordering anyway.

Comment: @Ben: Not in MySQL ...

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve here? I am not a MySQL programmer; however, as I understand SQL in general, every column that is not listed in the GROUP BY clause must be part of an aggregate like

```
SELECT
    MAX(id) AS max_id,
    chain, subchain, job_type
FROM
    `job_logs`
WHERE
    user_id = ? AND
    workflow_state = ?
GROUP BY
    chain, subchain, job_type
```

---

`SELECT *` in a grouping query will not work in most (if not all) SQL implementations.

---

**UPDATE**

In order to get the row with the highest id for each group you would have to embed the query above in an "outer" query.

```
SELECT *
FROM `job_logs`
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT
        MAX(id) AS max_id
    FROM
        `job_logs`
    WHERE
        user_id = ? AND
        workflow_state = ?
    GROUP BY
        chain, subchain, job_type 
)
```

This query is deterministic and should work with most SQL dialects.

---

Some query engines perform better with joins than with "IN subquery". You can give this a try

```
SELECT A.*
FROM
    `job_logs` A
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            MAX(id) AS max_id
        FROM
            `job_logs`
        WHERE
            user_id = ? AND
            workflow_state = ?
        GROUP BY
            chain, subchain, job_type) B
    ON A.id = B.max_id;
```

Comment: In MySQL it works. The query would return one row per group (the one with highest id).

Comment: @ypercube: I missed this possibility from other implementations!

Comment: @ypercube: "*works*" is relative. It will return non-deterministic results.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I don't disagree on that. I should have said something like: "It works, now, but one never knows when it will break."

Comment: I don't know if my new query solves the performance problems (it depends on how the query optimizer works), but it should solve the non-deterministic problem mentioned by a_horse_with_no_name.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM `job_logs`
  WHERE user_id = ? AND workflow_state = ?
  ORDER BY id DESC
  ) tmp
GROUP BY chain, subchain, job_type
```

Comment: Could you at least explain why you think this is better? (Also, please use `CTRL`+`K` or the `{}` button for code samples, not HTML tags.)